# Windows 10 high memory usage after some weeks - what is uwplauncher.ex?

Tags: windows, windows-10, memory, memory-leaks, uwp

I'm trying to find out what is causing the memory leak on some Windows 10 machines.
This is the comparison between right after reboot (left) and after about 6 weeks (right):
[comparison before/after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0BxdP.png)

When checking the processes tab I found many occurrences of uwplauncher.ex. I suppose this is part of the Universal Windows platform:
[uwplauncher](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9QfxP.png)

So my question is am I looking at the right spot? And is there a way to fix it, or to get rid of it.

Comment: [UWPLauncher](https://github.com/programmer2514/UWPLauncher/releases/tag/v2.1) appears to be third-party software.

Comment: I found out that it belongs to this service https://www.processchecker.com/file/CxAudioSvc.exe.html; deactivated the service and will observe it further.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the author has resolved their issue according to their last comment

Comment: just wanted to confirm that deactivating the service fixed the issue for me!

Comment: So submit a detailed answer

Answer (score 0):

I found out that it belongs to this service CxAudioSvc.exe. After deactivating the service the memory is stable again!